# How to remove some option from admin condition field in magento 2

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

How to remove some option from the admin condition field in Magento 2

[image: m]

Comment: Try removing it from here app/code/Magento/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product.php